# How to add a circle shaped button with swift?

Tags: ios, swift, button, interface-builder

I am trying to make this simple UI

Now the orange and darkblue are simple two views (the darkblue will have a nested tableview), but how would i make the button with some simple animation? Should i use CALayer or can i make use of the Interface Builder?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would have done it through code:

```
    let button2 = UIButton()
    button2.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)
    button2.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    button2.layer.borderWidth = 2
    button2.layer.cornerRadius = 50
    button2.setTitle("button", forState: .Normal)
    button2.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    button2.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    button2.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 233/255, green: 64/255, blue: 87/255, alpha: 1), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

self.view.addSubview(button1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This :- 
 Make sure your button's Height and width are the same

```
self.imgBg1.layer.cornerRadius = self.imgBg1.bounds.size.height / 2
self.imgBg1.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
self.imgBg1.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
self.imgBg1.clipsToBounds = true
self.imgBg1.contentMode = .ScaleToFill
```